# Webpack vendor bundle splitting

Tags: webpack, bundler, bundling-and-minification, webpack-5

been doing some googling and experimenting for a few hours now but I'm pretty stuck so here's an open question to you:

How can I split my webpack 5 vendors bundle into 2 parts?

Specifically, I want:

- vendors.bundle.js
- otherpackage.bundle.js

I.e imagine my node_modules folder looks like this:

```
├── bootstrap
├── tinymce
├── anotherpackage
├── anotherpackage2
```

What I would expect is 1 bundle with everything except tinymce and then another bundle with only tinymce.

What I've tried so far:

```
optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            // chunks: "all",  // If this is set my bundles in vendor get split into a million separate bundles
            // maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            // minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                tinymceVendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](tinymce)[\\/]/,
                    name: 'tinymce',
                    priority: 10,
                    chunks: "all",
                },
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/](node_modules)[\\/](!tinymce)[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: "all",
                }
            }
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked out for me. Keep in mind that I have webpack 4 on my project so some adjustments may require.

```
 optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
     vendor: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: 'vendors',
      chunks: 'all',
    },
   },
 },
},
```